# Nginx Multiple Domains One App and Server

Tags: django, nginx, webserver

I want to run multiple websites on the same django app and the same nginx server. 
I am successfully running http: //myip/ and http: //myip/name1 and http: //myid/name2

Now I want to link all these projects to myname.com and name1.com and name2.com

How should I change my nginx config file? The current version of the file is shown below. Thanks

```
upstream crsq {
      server localhost:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80 default;

    access_log /home/ubuntu/crsq-access.log;
    error_log /home/ubuntu/crsq-error.log error;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name crsq;

    location @proxy_to_crsq_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $http_x_forwarded_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http: //crsq;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        alias /home/ubuntu/crsq/crsq/robots.txt;
    }


    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_crsq_app;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/crsq/crsq/static;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
upstream crsq {
      server localhost:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80 ;

    access_log /home/ubuntu/crsq-access.log;
    error_log /home/ubuntu/crsq-error.log error;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name a.b.c;

    location @proxy_to_crsq_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $http_x_forwarded_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http: //crsq;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        alias /home/ubuntu/crsq/crsq/robots.txt;
    }


    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_crsq_app;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/crsq/crsq/static;
    }
}
server {

    listen 80 ;

    access_log /home/ubuntu/crsq-access.log;
    error_log /home/ubuntu/crsq-error.log error;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name b.c.d;

    location @proxy_to_crsq_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $http_x_forwarded_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http: //crsq;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        alias /home/ubuntu/crsq/crsq/robots.txt;
    }


    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_crsq_app;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/crsq/crsq/static;
    }
}
```